# updating an xml from another one using ids

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have to pick text from `translation.xml` and update `skeleton.xml`'s respective (where `@xid` =`@id`) nodes . in other words IF `@id` of `translation.xml` matches with `@xid` of `skeleton.xml`, the text content should be placed under `skeleton.xml` (+ if there is child element present the text content (inline element `i`, `b`, etc) also should go in respective parent element: Please see example below for more details:

Note: the inline element could be anything in skeleton.xml (its not restrict to b or i, so it should be generic)

*skeleton.xml*

```
    <root>
        <para a="b" b="c">
            <text xid="1">This is first para <b xid="2" a="c" b="d">This is bold <i xid="3" b="d" c="e">This is italics</i> rest of bold</b> rest of para</text>
        </para>
        <para><text xid="4">This is second para</text></para>
        <para><text xid="5">This is unchanged para</text></para>
        <para><text xid="6">This is unchanged para</text></para>
    </root>
```

*translation.xml*

```
    <root>
        <TU id="1">
            <source>This is first para <g id="2" tagName="b">This is bold <g id="3" tagName="i">This is italics</g> rest of bold</g> rest of para</source>
            <target>suum primum para <g id="2" tagName="b">Et hoc confidens, <g id="3" tagName="i">Hoc est, Te Deum</g> Reliqua autem audet,</g> reliqua autem verba haec</target>
        </TU>
        <TU id="4">
            <source>This is second para</source>
            <target>Hoc est secundum verba haec</target>
        </TU>
    </root>
```

*UpdatedSkeleton.xml*

```
    <root>
        <para a="b" b="c">
            <text xid="1">suum primum para <b xid="2" a="c" b="d">Et hoc confidens, <i xid="3" b="d" c="e">Hoc est, Te Deum</i> Reliqua autem audet,</b> reliqua autem verba haec</text>
        </para>
        <para><text xid="4">Hoc est secundum verba haec</text></para>
        <para><text xid="5">This is unchanged para</text></para>
        <para><text xid="6">This is unchanged para</text></para>
    </root>
```

I am trying with this code, but facing challenge to place text of inline content at the right place:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="2.0">
        <xsl:param name="translation" select="'file:/C:/Skeleton.xml'"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:variable name="doc">
            <xsl:copy-of select="doc($translation)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>            
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="text">
            <xsl:variable name="skelID" select="@xid"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$doc//*[$skelID=@id]">                
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$doc//*[$skelID=@id]/target"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the `<text>` node adding `<xsl:copy>` to your test block, and copy the `xid` attribute using `<xsl:attribute>`. For the unmodified nodes, you can use `<xsl:copy-of>` which copies the full tree, including attributes:

```
<xsl:when test="$doc//*[$skelID=@id]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="xid">
            <xsl:value-of select="$skelID"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$doc//*[$skelID=@id]/target"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:otherwise>
```

That will also copy the `<target>` element. You can remove it adding a template:

```
<xsl:template match="target">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

You also aren't replacing the `<g>` tag. I assume the `@tagName` attribute says what it's supposed to be transformed into. This should do it:

```
<xsl:template match="g">
    <xsl:element name="{@tagName}">
         <xsl:attribute name="xid">
              <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

I might have missed something, but that will probably solve most of your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, i am close. But how can i retain attributes of b and i tag, in skeleton.xml?